# Custom Authenticator not Called in Symfony 5.4

Tags: authentication, symfony, authenticator, symfony5.4

Currently I am developing Symfony application where I have multiple login form. For the login form I created the firewall and also created custom authenticator. New created custom authenticator added into the **services.yaml** file as well.

[image]

Authenticator working perfectly when added to the main firewall but it is not working with the oauth_login firewall.

New authenticator file is manually created.

When ever I try to login with *oauth_login* form, I am not able to login and also *OLoginFormAuthenticator* is not called.

Edit:

Following changes worked for me

[image]

Comment: In the future please refrain from using images for config.  Just use a code block.  Using both form_login and an authenticator for a given firewall is very unusual.  One or the other but not both.  If you have not already, verify that your Authenticator::supports method is working as expected.  The default implementation does not always work properly.  Firewalls can be tricky.  Sometimes it helps to start with a new project and minimal configuration.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I resolved the issue by disabling few of the setting in the oauth_login firewall.
TBH firewall is tricky with custom authenticator. 

I am editing the question with options that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

A few approaches and ideas:

##### Rename `custom_authenticator`

Try to name the property `custom_authenticators:`
(with an trailing `s`)
See [How to Write a Custom Authenticator](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/security/custom_authenticator.html) for more information.

---

##### Check `entry_point` target

Also your `entry_point` could be wrong!
Does your Authenticator implements `AuthenticationEntryPointInterface`? You maybe want a separate class for this.

See [The Entry Point](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entry_point.html) for more information.

---

#### Show all possible configurations of `security.yaml`

Type this in your terminal to see all possible configurations of `security.yaml`

```bash
php bin/console config:dump-reference security
```

Comment: It is a bit strange that dump-reference shows `custom_authenticators` but not `custom_authenticator` which can be used when you only have one authenticator.  Never ran across something like that before.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions Jonathan, My issue has bee resolved by making changes in security.yaml file. Removed few parameters and it worked like charm.

Comment: Glad it helped. Can you point out what exact parameters you removed? It may help others with similar problems in the future. If my answer helped you solving the problem, I'll be happy to have it marked as solution. Good day mate!

Comment: I edited my question and added the snippet image of my solution.

Comment: I am curious, do you know which property caused the error? Was it multiple properties? Or just the `entry_point`?